# IE 11 won't recognize Angular JS variable

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

The following code works fine in Chrome, but when viewed in Internet Explorer 11, the background color does not show up:

```
span.fa.fa-icon-only(style='background-color: #{{vehicle.visual_color}};', rr-tt='{{vehicle.color_name}}')
```

The visual_color variable is a hex color code, and for some reason it's not being recognized on IE. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Is it because `rr-tt` is an invalid attribute and IE doesn't like it?

Comment: can you make a fiddle so I can see it fail?

Comment: you could try using ng-style instead of style. I seem to recall that IE has some issues with using style dynamically like this

Comment: rr-tt is a custom angular directive, not invalid. That variable (color_name) is working fine, it is just the visual_color I am having trouble with.

Comment: yes I tried ng-style, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE has issues with dynamically changing a style tag as shown in this example http://plnkr.co/edit/lLvvDz?p=preview. Try using ng-style instead. e.g.:

```
span.fa.fa-icon-only(ng-style="{'background-color': '#' + vehicle.visual_color}", rr-tt='{{vehicle.color_name}}')
```